# using jslink to color code totals in a view when grouping

Tags: 2013, jslink

Im using JSlink to color code some cells in a view which works fine however i also need to color code the totals of the columns that are grouped.  Does anyone know how you can access the totals when grouped using jslink.  I cant find anything when googling

[image]

Comment: I hope you may have found the answers, for this you can always use jQuery selector to color the TD that contains the sum, need to look at the HTML for your list views.

Comment: You can change the rendering of a grouping, perhaps sums/totals can be changed as well.  Here's a link showing how to change the rendering of the group: http://prasadpathak.wordpress.com/tag/overridectx-templates-group/.  You'll have to debug to figure out what all you can touch.